# Why does map throw away type information when operating on DataArrays?

Tags: dataframe, julia

I'm trying to understand why this is happening even given the limitations of DataArrays.  Suppose you want to map over a DataArray of Int64s:

```
da = DataArray([1,2,3,4])
println(typeof(da))
println(typeof(map(a -> a^2, da))) # Returns an int for this input
println(typeof(map(a -> int(a^2), da))) # Cast the piecewise result to int
println(typeof(int(map(a -> a^2, da)))) # Cast the output DataArray{Any,1} to int
```

which results in

```
DataArray{Int64,1}
DataArray{Any,1}
DataArray{Any,1}
Array{Int64,1}
```

For an array,  `a = [1,2,3,4]`,  `map(a -> a^2, da)` returns an Array of Int64s as expected.  What is it about map and/or DataArrays that's causing type information to be lost here?  <strike>Is there any solution to preserve type information when you're working with a type which doesn't have a constructor that converts DataArray{Any,1} to DataArray{ThatType,1}, like Dates.DateTime?</strike>

Edit: convert works fine to make a DataArray{Any,1} a DataArray{ThatType,1} (well at least for DateTime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@which map(a -> a^2, da::DataArray{Int64, 1})  
map(f::Function,dv::DataArray{T,1}) at /home/omer/.julia/v0.3/DataArrays/src/datavector.jl:114
```

Checking the source;
https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataArrays.jl/blob/master/src/datavector.jl

```
# TODO: should this be an AbstractDataVector, so it works with PDV's?
function Base.map(f::Function, dv::DataVector)
    n = length(dv)
    res = DataArray(Any, n)
    for i in 1:n
        res[i] = f(dv[i])
    end
    return res
end
```

It's creating the type DataArray{Any,1} to return.

```
res = DataArray(Any, n)
```

You can check the answer given by James Fairbanks (1 Apr 04:12 2015)
http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.julia.user/month=20150401

Comment: Excellent catch, I forgot about map! which is what I should be using.